# Desktop: Horizontal picture/content, SmartPhone: Vertical picture/content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, smartphone

I am using a Wordpress responsive ready theme and it works quite well except for tables or div containers.

The main problem I have are my tables as shown on: [lichtundmusik.ch/vermietung/licht](http://www.lichtundmusik.ch/vermietung/licht/)

What I want:
When I watch the same page as mention above on my smartphone the picture should automaticaly change the order of the text and picture from horizontal to vertical

Illustration of what I want:[Link to the Illustration](http://www.lichtundmusik.ch/?p=3128)

One more difficulty:
Today it is the firt time I came a cross Bootstrap and I tried to implement it but unfortunately entering the Bootstrap code in the website header is changing the whole site.

Does somebody has a solution for me? Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your output is a table, you're going to have to play some tricks with CSS to make this work. [CSS-Tricks has a nice article explaining the basics](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/). TL;DR, you need to create another media query for small screens in your css that transforms your table cells into block elements:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

For the second part, Bootstrap is a huge framework and *will* change everything. For projects where I need responsiveness without the bulk, I've been using [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/), which gives a lot of the responsive goodies in a 4.4KB package.

Comment: hey cpilko, Many thanks for your help. It works perfectly fine!